# MacVim open vertical split upon launch

Tags: vim

How do I make mvim automatically split the window vertically upon launch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have mvim, but it probably reads `~/.vimrc`, so, try adding this line to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
vsplit
```

Comment: I thought of this too, but not sure how it would interact with other ways of starting vim, such as vimdiff.

Comment: So simple...I was thinking it had to be some autocmd call. This works great, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `vim +vsplit` to make vim run `:vsplit` after opening.

Comment: Just to add to this, if you want to open files in vertical splits use vim -O file1 file2.. etc.

Comment: I'm using macvim and usually launch by `cd` -ing into a directory and running the `mvim` launcher script. I'd like it to open up with two blank vsplits.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is getting here trying to find out about how to get external files to open in vertical splits, use this Terminal command:

```
defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMVerticalSplit YES
```

[Source](http://yjsoon.com/2011/08/making-macvim-open-files-in-vertical-splits).